# Protecting/unprotecting range based on another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with rows that need to be protected/unprotected based on the value of a cell. The default is that the rows are all unprotected. Column 24 contains a dropdown menu with the options "Waitlisted" and "Applied." When the cell is changed to "Applied" I want it to lock the entire row for editing. Then if "Applied" is later deleted, the protection should be removed. I've found some help on this site, but nothing specific enough to my situation as I have very limited experience in coding. Here is what I have so far:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Main' || e.range.columnStart != 24) return;
  var r = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,17);
  if (e.value == "Applied"){
    var protection = r.protect();
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  } else if (e.oldValue == "Applied"){
    var protections = 
sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for(var i=0;i<protections.length;i++){
  protection = protections[i];
      if(protection.getRange().getRow() == e.range.rowStart)
        protection.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

The protection aspect seems to be working fine. However when it should be unprotected, deleting "Applied" does not always work. Some rows will become unprotected while others will remain protected. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is giving an error because for a Spreadsheet object, you can use getRange method [1] only with A1 notation. You should use getActiveSheet() method [2] instead. With that change, as you said, your code doesn't work when you delete the "Applied" cell value. This is because when you just delete the cell value instead of changing it, the e.value and e.oldValue attributes comes undefined. To avoid this, you can use getValue method [3] to obtain the current value of the cell after the change and use it in the conditions. Here is the full code I tested:

```
function onEdit(e){
  //Get active Sheet instead of Spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() != 'Main' || e.range.columnStart != 24.0) {
    return;
  }
  var r = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,17);

  //Current value after the edit is made
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();

  if (cellValue == "Applied"){
    var protection = r.protect();
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  } 
  else if (cellValue == "Waitlisted" || cellValue == ""){
    //"If" to optimize code, beacuse if oldValue is Waitlisted it'll be desprotect it already
    if(e.range.oldValue != "Waitlisted") {
      var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      for(var i=0;i<protections.length;i++){
        protection = protections[i];
        if(protection.getRange().getRow() == e.range.rowStart) {
          protection.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()

Comment: Great no worries, if it worked you can select the answer as correct.