# Protect range (not entire rows, but multi height and partial width) based on another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

NOTE: my question is NOT answered by [Protecting/unprotecting range based on another cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892639/protecting-unprotecting-range-based-on-another-cell-value)
My question asks about a range, with only part of the rows selected, NOT entire rows as in that question. I have extensively searched the site and there isn't anything that answers my question.

Please read my query properly prior to linking it to something else that does not answer it.

QUESTION

I have created a shared test Google Sheets workbook ([TestWBook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WP3PbY6MjFevHOWv43W5jUy7Ds_2FDtI274IbEH-4Aw/edit)) to illustrate what I am trying to do. The 'Outgoing' sheet is where I need the restrictions to be applied; it is used to store order data.

The whole 'Outgoing' sheet (A1:AS), except range A2:M882, is currently protected so that only the owner and two other editors can make changes to it (let's call them editor1@email.com and editor2@email.com).

Other editors enter data in A2:M882 to specify new order requirements (which is why this range started by not being protected).

I now need to protect each row between columns A and M(active_row) from all editors but the owner and two other named editors (editor1@email.com and editor2@email.com) whenever a date is entered in column O (Date Sent) (or if that cell is not blank, either would work).

I don't want to protect an entire single row every time the script runs, as I don't want to end up with hundreds of protected ranges.

I want the protection to be applied dynamically to the range from A2 to M(active_row), so that effectively that one protected range is updated every time a date/value is entered in column O.

I have been looking through scripts for the last two days and cannot find a way to specify this dynamic range (sorry, I can adapt scripts but cannot write them up from scratch!)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName() != 'Outgoing') return;
  if (rng.getColumn() != 15) return;

  // save the protection parameters
  var p1 = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];

  // delete actual protection
  let protection = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (protection) { if (protection.canEdit()) { protection.remove(); } }

  // rebuild protection
  var p2 = sh.protect();
  p2.setDescription(p1.getDescription());
  p2.setWarningOnly(p1.isWarningOnly());
  if (!p1.isWarningOnly()) {
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(p1.getEditors());
  }

  // define new uprotected area
  p2.setUnprotectedRanges([sh.getRange('A' + rng.getRow() + ':M882')]);
}
```

Comment: Hello Mike, thank you for your reply.
Thank you so much for this, which works perfectly.
At first I misunderstood what you were doing with it, and then I spotted how you are actually just updating/revising the existing protection. Save the protection parameters, delete the sheet protection, and then reapply it whilst defining a new unprotected area. That also shows me the syntax to select ranges that don't span entire rows, which I had not seen anywhere else in this type of query. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you, yes, I will do. Your script also seems to be the slickest I have seen in relation to protecting ranges. I just wanted to add for others, that other ranges to be left unprotected can be added like this: // define new uprotected area p2.setUnprotectedRanges([sh.getRange('A' + rng.getRow() + ':M882'),sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow() + ':Q882')]); This would leave A_currentRow:M882, and P_currentRow:Q882 unprotected.

Comment: Just one more thing, to account for expanding sheets, just do not specify a row number for the end of the range. The current limit for the sheet is inserted automatically when the script runs, hence no need to change the script if the sheet expands. So my two sample ranges are specified as: p2.setUnprotectedRanges([sh.getRange('A' + rng.getRow() + ':M'),sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow() + ':Q')]);

Comment: that's what I usually do, but you mentioned in the post `except range A2:M882` so I keep 882 as you mentioned. However, the process is described and everyone can adapt to their needs. Thx for your feedback.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes, I specified an end row to the range as Google sheets always needed that when you apply protection manually. As I was trying the script it became evident that is not a requirement and in fact it is advantageous not to specify an end row. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hello Mike, I actually just spotted a small error in selecting the range to unprotect. As it is written it does not protect the row that was just edited, which should, in fact be protected.
So the script just needs a little tweak as you want the current row + 1:
So my two sample ranges are specified as: p2.setUnprotectedRanges([sh.getRange('A' + (rng.getRow()*1) + ':M'),sh.getRange('P' +  (rng.getRow()*1) + ':Q')]);

Comment: sorry, if i well undestand, try this modificatioun, at the end of the script `p2.setUnprotectedRanges([sh.getRange('A' + (+rng.getRow() + 1) + ':M')]);`