# Protecting/unprotecting range of rows based on another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-apps

I did manage to follow other example from older post from here> [Protecting/unprotecting range based on another cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892639/protecting-unprotecting-range-based-on-another-cell-value)

But the script didn't manage to protect/unprotect when few rows of value in column Q are dragged/changed together. How should i amend the script?

[image]

```
function onEdit(e){
  //Get active Sheet instead of Spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() != 'Sheet31' || e.range.columnStart != 17) {
    return;
  }
  var r = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,16);

  //Current value after the edit is made
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();

  if (cellValue !== ""){
    var protection = r.protect();
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  } 
  else if (cellValue == ""){
    //"If" to optimize code, beacuse if oldValue is Waitlisted it'll be desprotect it already
    if(e.range.oldValue != "") {
      var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      for(var i=0;i<protections.length;i++){
        protection = protections[i];
        if(protection.getRange().getRow() == e.range.rowStart) {
          protection.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your goal, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Unfortunately, I cannot know your function name from your question. So, in this modification, a sample function name of `installedOnEdit` is used. So, **please install OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`**. If you use `onEdit` as the function name, please rename it. Because, when `onEdit` is used as the function name, the script is run 2 times of the simple and the installable triggers. Please be careful about this.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var { range } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Sheet31' || range.columnStart != 17) {
    return;
  }
  var cellValues = range.getValues();
  cellValues.forEach(([cellValue], c) => {
    if (cellValue !== "") {
      var protection = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart + c, 1, 1, 16).protect();
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    } else {
      if (range.oldValue != "") {
        var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
        for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
          protection = protections[i];
          if (protection.getRange().getRow() == range.rowStart + c) {
            protection.remove();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- In this case, when the values are put to the column "Q", the script works.

### Added:

From your following reply,

> Noticed when i run your script modification, it will protect the rows 1 by one, not by group. Example, when is input value into Q2 to Q5, A2:P5 will be protected- is there any way can make it this way? Also if no way to do that, you think will it affect the sheet's performance when there's > 10k rows been protected this way?

In this case, I would like to recommend using Sheets API. When Sheets API is used in the above script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var { range, source } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Sheet31' || range.columnStart != 17) {
    return;
  }
  var cellValues = range.getValues();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var owner = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var ssId = source.getId();
  var { protectedRanges } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: 'Sheet31', fields: "sheets(protectedRanges)" }).sheets[0];
  var requests = cellValues.flatMap(([cellValue], c) => {
    if (cellValue !== "") {
      return { addProtectedRange: { protectedRange: { range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: range.rowStart + c - 1, endRowIndex: range.rowStart + c, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: 16 }, editors: { users: [owner] } } } }
    } else {
      if (protectedRanges && protectedRanges.length > 0) {
        var p = protectedRanges.find(f => f.range.startRowIndex == range.rowStart + c - 1);
        if (p) {
          return { deleteProtectedRange: { protectedRangeId: p.protectedRangeId } };
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
  });
  if (requests.length > 0) Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry the function is hidden just now. Yes, im indeed using onEdit. Noticed when i run your script modification, it will protect the rows 1 by one, not by group. Example, when is input value into Q2 to Q5, A2:P5 will be protected- is there any way can make it this way? Also if no way to do that, you think will it affect the sheet's performance when there's > 10k rows been protected this way?

Comment: @Kreng Kongkeng Thank you for replying. About `Example, when is input value into Q2 to Q5, A2:P5 will be protected- is there any way can make it this way? Also if no way to do that, you think will it affect the sheet's performance when there's > 10k rows been protected this way?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't notice this. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. For your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?